# how to put figures on a page in exam class!

Tags: floats, exam

**I am trying to put four figures in one page**. I have tried using `\clearpage`, `\afterpage{\clearpage}` with `afterpage` package as suggested and worked successfully in many other cases. I have also tried scaling down the image, using `h`, `H`, `p` etc. with `figure` command. None did work in my case.

**Help me please putting these four pictures on a page. My code at present is:**

```
\documentclass[addpoints,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx} %to display graphics!
\usepackage{afterpage}
\firstpagefootrule
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[] True/False questions.
\label{label:a}
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \caption{Figure of Q.\ref{label:a}}
            \label{label:q1}
        \end{figure}
    \end{parts}

\question[] True/False questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \caption{Figure of Q.2}
            \label{label:q2}
        \end{figure}
    \end{parts}

\question[] True/False questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \caption{Figure of Q.3}
            \label{label:q3}
        \end{figure}
    \end{parts}

\question[] True/False questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \caption{Figure of Q.4}
            \label{label:q4}
        \end{figure}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I am unable to upload the image `test.jpg` (*of size 168x126*) as well as the pdf I have created by running the above code. I am sorry for not able to upload the output I got.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default maximum number of floats per page is three. In your case, you want the images to appear at precise locations, so don't use the floating environment `figure`; instead you can use `minipage`s and `\captionof` from the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages to get captions:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %to display graphics!
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\firstpagefootrule
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[] True/False questions.
    \label{label:a}
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2] True or False.
            An image:

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
                \captionof{figure}{Figure of Q.\ref{label:a}}
                \label{label:q1}
\end{minipage}
        \end{parts}


\question[] True/False questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure of Q.2}
            \label{label:q2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{parts}

\question[] True/False questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure of Q.3}
            \label{label:q3}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{parts}

\question[] True/False questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] True or False.
        An image:

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure of Q.4}
            \label{label:q4}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Thanks once again for another new testing command "**demo**" used in graphicx package. You know I was wondering why all black rectangles after running the modified code provided by you successfully. I even changed the picture to another and yet black rectangles. Later I put tikzpicture and show the figure, then I realize that it must be something to do with graphicx package and found the command. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Khabba Sorry about that; when I use `demo` I usually place a little note warning about its usage and meaning, but I forgot it in my answer to your question; I'll add it right now.