# A new figure environment for the exam class

Tags: floats, exam

The incompatibility of having a float inside the solutions box of the exam class is somewhat well known. Multiple solutions for this exist, almost all of which use [some variant of the caption package and the minipage environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71373/how-to-put-figures-on-a-page-in-exam-class).

Why doesn't simply wrapping the figure inside a minipage environment work?

I tried

```
\renewenvironment{figure}{\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}}{\end{minipage}}
```

Comment: Does the exam class define a figure environment which you can redefine?

Comment: No. But graphicx(?) does.

Comment: I guess its time for a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 3):

`exam` is based on article, and thus the figure environment is
defined. You can define a new environment using a minipage, but i
do not recommend to redefine the original `figure`-environment. 
But doing this, the order of the figures (and the captions) can
be messed up pretty badly. You need to decide, let them all
float, or let none float.

--Edit--
@tohecz made me aware of the solution environment. This is a
serious thing. Traditional floats will just *be lost*. The just
defined `questionfigure` environment works, but there is another thing. 
There is a switch to print answers, or *not*. If not, the counter
will still be `refstepped` and can make everything look *more
than odd* if no answers are printed. I would recommend to define
separate environments for questions (always printed) and
answers/solutions (only printed if toggled). This would take care
of the numbering. But then a question arises: Do you need figures
that can be referenced if inside a framed (default) environment?

I defined two separate environments and gave them pretty dumb names. Referencing to figures in question will always work, no matter if called from a question or an answer. Referencing from answers to other answers (or rather the pics in them) works as well. Referencing an answerfigure in a question will not work if `printanswers` is false, but what would be the use-case? »Ha Ha, there will be a real great image in the answer, but can't see it!«

Disclaimer: If you compile the following (and you should) you need to use your imagination. No ducks were harmed while writing this answer.

````
\documentclass[
answers
]{exam}%based on article
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\DeclareNewTOC[
name=questionFigure,
listname={List of questionfigures},
type=qfigure,
nonfloat]{loq}
\DeclareNewTOC[
name=answerFigure,
listname={List of answerfigures},
type=afigure,
nonfloat]{loa}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theqfigure{\thenumquestions}
\newenvironment{questionfigure}{%
    \begin{center}%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}%
    \def\@captype{qfigure}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{center}%
}
\renewcommand\theafigure{\thenumquestions-\alph{afigure}}
\newenvironment{answerfigure}{%
    \begin{center}%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}%
    \def\@captype{afigure}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{center}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\rplcPic{\rule{4cm}{3cm}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\listofqfigures
%Print the list of afigures only if answers toggled
\ifprintanswers
\listofafigures
\fi
\begin{questions}
    \question Name a place where the lights are always on.
        \begin{solution} The light in my fridge is always
            on. 
        \begin{answerfigure}
            \rplcPic
            \caption{Almost all refridgerators
                provide the feature of \emph{eternal}
            light.}
        \end{answerfigure}
        \end{solution}
        \question Look at the following picture. What do
        you conclude?
        \begin{questionfigure}
        \rplcPic
        \caption{An open fridge. What do you conclude?}
        \label{fridge}
    \end{questionfigure}
    \begin{solution}
        Seeing the footprints in the butter, i can conclude that there must
        have been an elephant in there earlier.
    \end{solution}
    \question Homer was one of the greatest greek
    philosophers. Sum up his philosophy in as few words as
    possible.
    \begin{solution}
        Beer, Donuts.
    \end{solution}
    \question Nucleaar weapons are terrible. Describe and
    explain the physical reactions of an atomic bomb.
    \begin{solution}
        A picture is worth more than a thousand words.
        \begin{answerfigure}
            \begin{verbatim}
                  _-^--^=-_
           _.-^^          -~_
        _--                  --_
        <                       >)
        |                        |
        \._                   _./
           ```--. . , ; .--'''
             | |   |
              .-=||  | |=-.
              `-=#$%&%$#=-'
             | ;  :|
        _____.,-#%&$@%#&#~,._____
            \end{verbatim}
            \caption{BOOOM}
            \label{boom}
        \end{answerfigure}
    \end{solution}
    \question When to \emph{Duck and cover}?
    \begin{solution} See \autoref{boom}!
    \end{solution}
\question{Is it easy to change a refridgerator light bulb?}
\begin{solution} Sure, according to \autoref{fridge} an elephant
    lives in there. Just place the light bulb inside, the
    elephant will do the work.
\end{solution}
\question You see a block of iron glowing with an orange color
(see the picture).
What does that tell you about the temperature?
\begin{questionfigure}
    {\color{orange!40!white}{\rplcPic}}
    \caption{A gloowing block of iron}
\end{questionfigure}
\begin{solution} Oh, that's hot. Can't touch this!
\end{solution}
\question Did you ever use Plan 9 from Bell Labs?
\begin{solution} 42! Glenda is cool. See \autoref{boom}. 
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
````

Comment: Thanks!! I was away from work for a few days. Yes, I do need the ability to refer to these figures.

Comment: @user2751530 I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @user2751530 Sorry, your request somehow got lost in my stack. I extended my answer a little bit.